# Can I install a different Samba client on OSX Lion?

Tags: osx-lion, samba, smb, cifs

Right now I am using the standard OSX Lion Samba Client to connect to my Windows 2008 Samba Shares. Is there an alternative client to the one that ships with OSX Lion? I am experiencing software incompatibilities with the one that ships with OSX Lion.

Comment: Why are you so sure this is a basic compatibility issue? OSX network software is pretty thoroughly tested. I'd suggest rewriting your question to ask for help figuring why your connection is failing. Incude error messages and setup info. It's very likely that there's some simple configuration problem that would be fairly easy to fix.

Answer (score 4):

Lion uses Apple's homegrown SMB software and not Samba. You can try [SMBUp](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/41541/smbup) or [DAVE](http://www.thursby.com/products/dave.html) to replace Apple's somewhat borked SMB implementation.

Comment: I grabbed DAVE, but we ultimately worked around Apple's implementation of SMB.